# how to convert a string to palindrome with minimum number of removals of characters of the string?

Tags: string, algorithm

suppose the string is "anuja", the output should be 2 because if I remove the characters 'u' and 'n', the given string becomes a palindrome.Thus the output should be the minimum number of removals.
more examples: input string: "ababa"
output: 0 (no removal needed)
input string:"abcdba"
output: 1 (removal of 'c' or 'd')
please explain the algorithm.

Comment: nice problem. what have you tried so far and where's the problem with your solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let `dp[i, j] = minimum number of removals needed to convert the substring [i, j] to a palindrome`. We have:

```
dp[i, i] = 0 for all i (every single character is a palindrome)
```

To find `dp[i, j]`, let's consider a random string. We have two possibilities:

1. The first and last characters are equal: `a[i] == a[j]`. In this case, we can reduce the problem to finding the minimum number of characters that need to be deleted in order to make the substring `[i+1, j-1]` a palindrome.
2. The first and last characters are not equal: `a[i] != a[j]`. In this case, we need to remove one of them. We'll remove that which leads us to a better solution.

So we have:

```
dp[i, j] = dp[i + 1, j - 1]                     # if a[i] == a[j]
           min(dp[i + 1, j], dp[i, j - 1]) + 1  # otherwise
```

For your example of `anuja`. we'd get:

```
  | 1 2 3 4 5
-------------
1 | 0 1 2 2 2
2 |   0 1 2 3
3 |     0 1 2
4 |       0 1
5 |         0
```

Note that the matrix is computed starting with the main diagonal and continuing upwards, in order, with the diagonals parallel to the main diagonal. The answer is `dp[1, n]`.

This is similar to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but it only considers removals.

Comment: @Khushboo if an answer answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark to the left of it. You can also upvote it, if you wish, by clicking the up arrow (`^`) in the same location.

Comment: how are you calculating the dp[i+1][j] if you do not know dp[i][j]

Comment: Could you explain the 0s in the diagonal

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula dp[i, i] = 0 for all i (every single character is a palindrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the edit distance (levenshtein distance) from the string to its reverse (ignoring the replacements). The desired value will be the half of this value.

This problem is similar to [UVA 10739](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/107/p10739.pdf). Here's an [example implementation](https://github.com/juanplopes/icpc/blob/master/uva/10739.cpp).

An example implementation (adapted to your case) can be:

```cpp
string P, Q;
getline(cin, P);
Q = string(P.rbegin(), P.rend());
int p = P.size(), q = Q.size();

for(int i=0; i<=p; i++) { T[i][0] = i; }
for(int i=0; i<=q; i++) { T[0][i] = i; }

for(int i=1; i<=p; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=q; j++) {
        if (P[i-1] == Q[j-1])
            T[i][j] = T[i-1][j-1];
        else
            T[i][j] = min(T[i-1][j], T[i][j-1]) + 1;
    }
}

cout << "Case " << tt << ": " << T[p][q]/2 << endl;
```

Comment: In the problem you linked to, you can add, remove and replace characters. Here you can only remove them. Why are the problems the same?

Comment: @IVlad you are right, although add and remove are the same operation from different point-of-views. Then it's just a matter of removing a T[i-1][j-1] from the recurrence, but you've already done that in your answer. I'll leave this answer here just because I think the rationale of computing the edit distance between the string and its reverse is useful :)

Comment: @Juan Lopes..Thank you for answering.. it helped.